# Java Hashmap clears every time I add a new set of data

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to store the total times a word is used in a stream of tweets. Each time a tweet is received I split it into an array and then iterate over the array to add each word to the hashmap, or increase it's value if it already exists. My problem is that the hashmap appears to be blank each time a tweet is received.

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> map;

private void createDataStore() {
    map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

protected void addKeywords(Status status) {
    // get tweet
    String str = status.getText();
    // split into an array
    String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
    // vars used in loop
    String thisStr;
    int wordTot;

    for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
        // get word from array
        thisStr = splited[i];
        // check if the word is in the hashmap
        if (!map.containsKey(thisStr)) {
            // already exists
            map.put(thisStr, 1);
        } else {
            // its a new word!
            wordTot = map.get(thisStr);
            wordTot++;
            map.put(thisStr, wordTot);
        }

    }

}

private void traceTotals() {
    System.out.println("trace totals");

    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you using this code? Are you calling `createDataStore` for each tweet?

Comment: How do you call these three methods?

Comment: Of course there is nothing to do with `HashMap`. The behavior depens mostly on method call sequences and the contents of `Status`. Just put additional logging in `addKeywords()` and `createDataStore()` and you will see where is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it.remove();` actually removes the entry from the `HashMap`. Calling `it.remove();` is not required to iterate through a `Collection`, it should only be used to remove elements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the it.remove(); was causing this. I've commented this line and the code is working fine.

Can anyone explain what's going on?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. createDataStore() is only called once. addKeywords() is called each time a tweet is received and traceTotals() is called immediately afterwards to show the new data.

Comment: Your `traceTotals()` with `remove()` present effectively wipes out your map.

Comment: It looks like you call `traceTotals` after you receive each tweet where you iterate over the map and remove every single entry in it. that could explains why the map is empty when the next tweet comes.

Answer (score 0):

it.remove() Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator.this statement removes the collection